# javascript - change message box title

Tags: javascript

how can i change the title of message box in java script
plese given me a code for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change for standard alert() of javascript.

go through this link- http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the native `alert()`, you can't. It is browser implemented.

If using a custom modal, simply change the HTML as you would any other element.

Comment: act i have used the dropdown in the iphone with html page but when the