# How to change the message box title?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image]

How to change the title of this message box in asp.net?

this heading appears in IE.

Do Help...

Comment: Obligatory jQueryUi alternative; http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: I have added a working example to the original question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title/50252295#50252295) using jqueryui-dialog if anyone interested.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. There is no API to do this and the default title is an anti-phishing security feature.

If you want that much control over the appearance of your alert messages, then you will have to build your own in the DOM instead of using native ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change javascript message box title. check this out: 
[**How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)  
 I recommend you to use custom message box instead of `alert();`.
  For example you can use some jquery plugins like:  
 [**Stylish JavaScript Dialog (Alert, Confirm, Prompt) Boxes**](http://www.bitrepository.com/stylish-javascript-dialog-boxes.html) 
 or
 [**Dialog Jquery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, this is determined by the browser, for the user's safety and security.If really want that use jQuery dialog boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh...no you can't.

Its a security/anti-phishing feature.

More details

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090180/javascript-change-message-box-title)

and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172022/change-title-of-javascript-alert)